# how to validate unique email id using jquery validation in edit form in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-validation-engine

I am working on ruby on rails and using jquery validation in my application.
In Employee Master new form email id uniqueness remote is working fine  but in edit form email id uniqueness same remote i am using, remote call is working same as new page.

employeee_masters/new

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5dsw.png)

employee edit page

employee_masters/12/edit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYb4o.png)

**employee_masters/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@employee_master, :html => {class: "form-horizontal",id: "employee_validation"}) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-horizontal ">
        <div class="form-group">
     <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :fname, class:"form-control" %></div>
     </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">Middle Name</label>                                          
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :mname, class:"form-control" %></div>
        </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">Last Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
   <%= f.text_field :lname, class:"form-control" %></div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" 
        for="textInput-modal-markup">Email Id</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
           <%= f.text_field :email_id, class:"form-control" %> 
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>

   <p style="float:right;">
    <%= f.submit "Save" ,style:"float:right", class:"btn btn- 
   primary btn-xs" %>&nbsp; <p>
   <br>
    <hr>
 </div>
```

**employee_masters/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@employee_master, :html => {class: "form-horizontal",id: "employee_validation"}) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-horizontal ">
        <div class="form-group">
     <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :fname, class:"form-control" %></div>
     </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">Middle Name</label>                                          
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :mname, class:"form-control" %></div>
        </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">Last Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
   <%= f.text_field :lname, class:"form-control" %></div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label" 
        for="textInput-modal-markup">Email Id</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
           <%= f.text_field :email_id, class:"form-control" %> 
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>

   <p style="float:right;">
    <%= f.submit "Save" ,style:"float:right", class:"btn btn- 
   primary btn-xs" %>&nbsp; <p>
   <br>
    <hr>
 </div>
```

**employee_master_validation.js**

```
   $( "#employee_validation" ).validate({
   errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'desc',
    ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',
     rules: {
       "employee_master[fname]" : { required: true, lettersonly:true, minlength:3,maxlength:25 },
       "employee_master[lname]" : {required: true, lettersonly:true,minlength:1,maxlength:25 },
       "employee_master[email_id]" : {required: true, email: true,remote: "/employee_masters/check_email_id/"}
     },
     messages: {
       "employee_master[fname]" : { required: "Fname is required", lettersonly:"Enter only letters" ,
                                       minlength: "Fname should be atleast 3 charecter",
                                       maxlength: "Fname should not be more than 25 charecter"},
       "employee_master[lname]" : {required: "Last name is required", lettersonly:"Enter only letters",
                                     minlength: "Lname should be atleast 1 charecter",
                                     maxlength: "Lname should not be more than 25 charecter" },

       "employee_master[email_id]" : {required: "Email id is required", email: "Enter valid email id",remote: "Email Id already Exists"},

     },
    highlight: function (element) {
      $(element).closest('.col-sm-8').removeClass('success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
      element.addClass('valid').closest('.col-sm-8').removeClass('error').addClass('has-success');
    }
 });
```

**employee_master_controllers.rb**

```
  def check_email_id
     @employee= 
      EmployeeMaster.find_by_email_id(params[:employee_master] 
                                                [:email_id])
        respond_to do |format|
       format.json {render :json => !@employee}
     end
    end
```

While editing error message is coming "Email is already Exists " ,please tell me how to resolve this issue, how to write a code for edit validation form

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? I need a couple more words of explanation

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i have updated my query

Comment: which query? I don't see any model code. I believe you did not correctly understand your issues. It is hard to solve issues that have such long question. The best thing is to better anaylize your issues, understand what is your problem and just paste 4 lines of code which represent your problem.

Comment: I got the solution for this issue